# Failed to instantiate module ui-bootstrap for Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issues getting angular-bootstrap to load in my app

```
 [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module RecipeSite due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui-bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui-bootstrap' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.
```

I have ui-bootstrap dependency in my module and I imported the library
but I'm still having the issue. I've been looking at posts similar to this and playing with it, but I can't seem to get the console error to go away.
Any suggestions?

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('RecipeSite', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui-bootstrap']);
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="RecipeSite">
<head>
    <title>Directives Practice</title>


<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6"> 


            {{"Test Site"}}


            </div>
</div> <!--end row-->
<hr class="hrstyle">

        </div> <!--end header-->


    </div> <!--end container-->

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">




</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you have to install the `angular-bootstrap` with bower:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
```

Also you have a typo, it's `ui.bootstrap`, not `ui-bootstrap`.

Change your `module` to:

```
var app = angular.module('RecipeSite', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

Comment: I updated that and now get failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available!

Comment: Don't change your question! Or the answers will make absolutely no sense!

Comment: Sorry. I won't touch that part then. But in the code I do get that error now

Comment: I installed the library through bower and I updated ui-bootstrap in the dependency injection to ui.bootstrap, but issue still persists

Comment: It should work.. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gvpqc69teVSS0VMUWlVv?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks I got it working. I stopped the live-server and restarted the server and it picked up the library. Thanks for you help!