# How correctly use ui-bootstrap in AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use dropdown button in my project but I can't do it.
I run the command:

```
npm install angular-ui-bootstrap
```

After this, I included:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap',
   ...
])
```

Finally in my page:

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
                <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The dropdown button doesn't work. 
Is there anything to include after installing ui-bootstrap?
Thanks

Comment: did you skip a step of adding your script: `<script src="lib/ui-bootstrap-tpls-X.X.X.js"></script>`? (_after loading `angular.js` script; order matters_)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to instantiate module ui-bootstrap for Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38943949/failed-to-instantiate-module-ui-bootstrap-for-angular)

Answer (score 0):

you must first add `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` and then add `ui.bootstrap.css` angular-animate.js and angular.touch.js. 
.then add ngAnimate and angular-touch dependencies before ui.bootstrap

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ngAnimate','angular-touch','ui.bootstrap',...
```

> he only required dependencies are:
>
> AngularJS (requires AngularJS 1.4.x or higher, tested with 1.6.1).
>   0.14.3 is the last version of this library that supports AngularJS 1.3.x and 0.12.0 is the last version that supports AngularJS 1.2.x. Angular-animate (the version should match with your angular's, tested
>   with 1.6.1) if you plan in using animations, you need to load
>   angular-animate as well. Angular-touch (the version should match with
>   your angular's, tested with 1.6.1) if you plan in using swipe actions,
>   you need to load angular-touch as well. Bootstrap CSS (tested with
>   version 3.3.7). This version of the library (2.5.0) works only with
>   Bootstrap CSS in version 3.x. 0.8.0 is the last version of this
>   library that supports Bootstrap CSS